# Gradle error HttpRequestException: Could not GET with 3.1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I hope many developers might have faced the below attached gradle errors with Android Studio 3.1.4 and found a solution too. So, could you please help me come out of this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: while you click on Rebuild Project, it will shows a baloon at bottom right corner to agree with their terms. So click on it and it will start downloading of respective files. then it will be solved.

Comment: @ParthPatel when I rebuild, it shows only the balloon notification and it is not downloading any files after clicking on it, Pls provide some clarity

Comment: Bro, I said click on Agree with the terms link which highlighted with blue color.

Comment: Solution Setting > Build,Execution,Deployment > Gradle >Android Studio > Enable embedded Maven repository and after the sync, it will ask for downloading the missing files

Comment: okay, I have enabled it prior, so I forgot to tell you.